# Is there any way that smart contract can access xacml policies?

Tags: blockchain, contract-design, access

I am trying to implement role based access control model using blockchain. How do i store these policies? Later my smartcontract should be able to allow or deny the rquest of user based on policie.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think its doable. Yes, users would be permitted or denied access to a function based on their address. Its worth noting that such restriction would not apply to read-only operations owing to the transparent nature of ethereum.

A good starting point is role-based access control in the open zeppelin library.

https://openzeppelin.org/api/docs/ownership_rbac_RBAC.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, I don't want to assign a role to an address, my data is something like <user id, user, role> and < role permission>. How do I store them? There are 1000 users.

Comment: Using user id instead of address is probably a mistake. Ethereum provides a very strong user authentication system. Using it is usually the right direction.